# Update all values of a column to lowercase

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have something like this

```
uid    tag
1      HeLLo
2      heLLO
3      HELLO
4      hello
```

How can I update all values in the "tag" column to:

```
uid    tag
1      hello 
2      hello 
3      hello 
4      hello
```

using MySQL?

Answer (score 305, accepted):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower

```
UPDATE table_name SET tag = LOWER(tag)
```

Comment: Note, this doesn't work right when your database uses case insensitive matching.

Comment: How will this work with email adresses? Name@domain.com Will the @ change?

Comment: `UPDATE table_name SET tag = BINARY LOWER(tag)` for case insensitive matching.

Comment: @BjörnC - upper/lower only changes letters; all other characters are unchanged.

Answer (score 68):

[**LOWER()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower)

```
update table set tag = LOWER(tag)
```

Comment: I get this error when I try this query HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 6):

Version for case-insensitive matching and including a "WHERE" clause if you don't want to update the entire column:

```
UPDATE table 
SET tag = LOWER(tag)
WHERE LOWER(tag) != tag
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

The COLLATE line will make it work if your database uses case insensitive matching, as mine does.

Comment: I get this error when I try this query HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
update `table` set `column_name` = LOWER(column_name without quotation)
```