# UPDATE an array of strings to LOWER (lowercase)

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to update a column that is an array of strings to convert each of those to lowercase?

Like this [Update all values of a column to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160873/update-all-values-of-a-column-to-lowercase/6160893) , but for an array of strings.

Example of data:

```
id | tags                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
---+---------------------------------------------------------------
58 | 
87 | {Pasta}
94 | {trendy,Supper,"Restaurant casual"}
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could cast the array to text, apply `lower()` on that, then cast it back to an array:

```
update the_table
  set tags = lower(tags::text)::text[];
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create a string from the array, lower case it, and revert it to array in one go - try:

```
create table myTest (
id bigserial primary key,
arrayText text[]);

insert into myTest (arrayText) values ('{"aPPLE","GRAPE","piNEappLe","CHErry"}');
select * from myTest;
update myTest set arrayText = string_to_array(LOWER(array_to_string(arraytext,',')),',') where id = 1;
select * from myTest;`
```