# update column value from upper to lower case in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle10g

A table has huge data in which one column wrongly loaded data in upper case instead of lower case,
For eg,

Table test structure like below

```
column1 column2 column3  
and      123      890  
AND      234      923  
and      125      345  
bet      098      234  
BET      267      065  

Now i want to update above table like below  

column1 column2 column3  
and      123      890  
and      234      923  
and      125      345  
bet      098      234  
bet      267      065
```

Note: I want to update only uppercase data to lower case without touching other fields.
Its a huge data table i cannot update each row manually

I would like get suggestion from techies here

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what issue are you facing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update all values of a column to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160873/update-all-values-of-a-column-to-lowercase)

Comment: Side note: If for that column, only lower case should be allowed, just create a check constraint.